# How to perform basic OR and AND conditioning in IF statement in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Like the title says, I'm just trying to use OR and AND conditions within my IF statement in access, for example:

```
iif(A=" " OR A=0 AND B>=2,"Test1","Test2")
```

I'm trying to figure out what the correct way to write this would be.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want parentheses:

```
iif( (A = " " OR A = 0) AND B >= 2, "Test1", "Test2")
```

However, this does not really make sense.  Is `A` a number or a string?  If a string, then *all* comparisons should be to strings:

```
iif( (A = " " OR A = "0") AND B >= 2, "Test1", "Test2")
```

If both are numbers, then the comparison to `" "` is meaningless.  You probably want to compare to `NULL`:

```
iif( (A is null OR A = 0) AND B >= 2, "Test1", "Test2")
```

Comment: I tried adding parentheses but it returns a #Error. Both A and B are numbers

Comment: @Roger . . . The parentheses should be fine.  Be sure they balance.

Comment: Yup you're right, the issue was just with the missing IS NULL. Thanks so much!